# jQuery .toggle not working on CSS intersection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to toggle the visibility of a CSS intersection when a radio button is clicked. The code underneath unfortunately does not seem to work. It does work when .css('display','block') but that does not provide the toggle functionality required.

HTML:

```
  <div class="input">
    <label for="type">What is your aim?</label>
    <div class="radio">
      <div class="radio-el">
        <label for="dc">Data Collection</label>
        <input id="dc" type="radio" name="aim" value="dataCollection">
      </div>
      <div class="radio-el">
        <label for="inc">Opt-in Incentive</label>
        <input id="inc" type="radio" name="aim" value="incentive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input optin">
    <p>All the additional form elements go here</p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.input.optin{
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=aim]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'incentive') {
        $('.input.optin').toggle();
    }
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zomer/reL5v4tx/)

Answer (score 3):

[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) method accepts a boolean to show or hide:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=aim]').change(function(){
    $('.input.optin').toggle($(this).val() === 'incentive');
});
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it only works if there's no CSS hiding the additional form data in the first place. If you take the css away the toggle works but it will already show the additional form elements.

Comment: @summer Is it what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/jmrkotoh/   I'm sorry but i've really really hard time to understand what you mean?!

Comment: @Wolff Thanks mate. That's pretty much what I mean. Preferably I would have the radio buttons unchecked at the beginning and only after clicking the '.incentive' radio button would the hidden elements appear.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a toggle, but at specific value show or hide like this:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=aim]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'incentive') {
    $('.input.optin').show();
  } else {
    $('.input.optin').hide();
  }
});
```

Is correct ?

[JSFiddle for test it](https://jsfiddle.net/oa4t6Loa/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('input[type=radio][name=aim]').change(function(){
      var $x=$(this).val();
      if ($x=='incentive') {
        $('.optin').toggle();
      } else {
        $('.optin').show();
      }
    });

 });
```

`